# How could I insert a new item in a existing node in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to know how i could add a new value to a existing child or node in Firebase.

The structure of my Firebase child is like this

[image]

and i would like to insert a new value and upload this specific child.
The result i would like to get is the next

[image]

As you can see I inserted the key --> "**key**" and the value "***-LEkCo-4bwHd8ThOM27i***"

Finally trying to specify more.. the structure of my entire Database is the next

[image]

I did it with the Firebase console but i would like to do from my app.

Any thoughts??
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`updateChildren()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#updateChildren(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%3E)):

> To simultaneously write to specific children of a node without overwriting other child nodes, use the `updateChildren()` method.

```
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(randomid);
Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String,Object>();
updates.put("userid", newID);
ref.updateChildren(updates);
```

Comment: Perfect! It is important to highlight that the type for the Map must be <String, Object>, otherwise it won't work.